# Код вроде рабочий, но система не принимает его

Tags: python

На склад, который имеет форму прямоугольного параллелепипеда, привезли ноутбуки, упакованные в коробки. Каждая коробка также имеет форму прямоугольного параллелепипеда. По правилам хранения коробки с ноутбуками должны быть размещены на складе с выполнением следующих двух условий:

> 1. Стороны коробок должны быть параллельны сторонам склада.
> 2. Коробку при помещении на склад разрешается расположить где угодно (с выполнением предыдущего условия), в том числе на другой коробке, но
>    все коробки должны быть ориентированы одинаково (т.е. нельзя одну
>    коробку расположить “стоя”, а другую —“лежа”)

Напишите программу, которая по размерам склада и размерам коробки с ноутбуком определит максимальное количество ноутбуков, которое может быть размещено на складе.

Входные данные
Программа получает на вход шесть натуральных чисел. Первые три задают длину, высоту и ширину склада. Следующие три задают соответственно длину, высоту и ширину коробки с ноутбуком.

Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести одно число — максимальное количество ноутбуков, которое может быть размещено на складе.

> входные данные 100 200 300 1 2 3 выходные данные 1000000
>
> входные данные 100 200 300 3 2 1 выходные данные 1000000
>
> входные данные 100 100 1 2 2 2 выходные данные 0
>
> входные данные 7 7 7 3 3 3 выходные данные 8

Вроде всё верно, код работает, выводит нужные числа из примеров, но проверяющая система даёт только 12 баллов из 100. Что с кодом не так?
P.S.: я считаю пустоты, которые остались после погрузки коробок и вычитаю их из объёма склада.
Возможно я намудрил и это дело решается куда проще, но всё же мне хотелось бы знать в чём моя ошибка. Заранее спасибо
Сам код:

```
x = int(input())

y = int(input())

z = int(input())


a = int(input())

b = int(input())

c = int(input())


v1 = x * y * z

v2 = a * b * c


r = [x, y, z]

t = [a, b, c]

o = max(r)

o1 = min(r)

p = max(t)

p1 = min(t)

r.remove(max(r))

r.remove(min(r))

t.remove(max(t))

t.remove(min(t))

o2 = max(r)

p2 = max(t)



e = v1 - (o2 * o1 * (o % p) + (o * o1 * (o2 % p2) - o * (o2 % p2)) + (o2 * o * (o1 % p1) - o * (o2 % p2) - o2 * (o % p)))

print(e // v2)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Есть шесть способов повернуть коробки перед помещением их в склад.

Comment: у вас очень упрощённый подход, вы рассматриваете лишь частный случай размещения коробок